# Get variable from a function

Tags: php

I have two functions and i want to get a variable in the first function into the second one. My code is :

```
$adresse = array();

function first( $atts ) {

    global $adresse;
    $atts = shortcode_atts( 
        array(
            'url' => '',
        ),
        $atts
    );

    $adresse['url'] = $atts['url'];
    return $adresse['url'];

}


function second() {
    global $adresse;
    echo $adresse['url'];
 }
```

I want to get result of adresse in the second function.
Thanks for your help

Comment: call `first()` from `second()`, since you are returning the value of `$adresse` in `first()`

Comment: What your real purpose?

Comment: I tried to call first($adresse); in the second function but does not work. I want to transfer the result of a shortcode to the second function.

Comment: Have you tried in second function `echo first($your_var);` ?

Comment: Yes, it does not work

Comment: can you give me a sample/example of the `$atts` you are passing to the first function ?

Comment: $atts is just an array contain the url

Comment: Try this since you are working with global variable , no need to return variable if you access the global one directly `$adresse = array();

function first( $atts ) {

global $adresse;
$adresse=shortcode_atts(['url'=>''],$atts);

}


function second() {
global $adresse;
first(array('url'=>'url1'));
        echo $adresse['url'];
 }
second();
?>` sorry for bad code and if you are sure that the array always have 'url' key you can use `function first( $atts ) {
global $adresse;
$adresse['url']=$atts['url'];
}`

Comment: Thanks for this solution, with your code i obtain "url1" as output with echo $adresse['url'];. How to get the real value ? Thanks

Comment: just change the param you send to the `first($param)` to the array that has the value you need

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use `class` for this:

```
class Address {
    private $addresse;

    public function setUrl(string $url=''): void {
        $this->addresse['url'] = $url;
    }

    public function getUrl(): string {
        return $this->addresse['url'];
    }
}
```

And then use it like this:

```php
$addr = new Address();
$atts = shortcode_atts( 
array(
  'url' => '',
), 
$atts
);

$addr->setUrl($atts['url']);

echo $addr->getUrl();
```

Details may change on your exact wish, ofc.

Comment: if we are sure there is 'url' key in the array, this is great answer

Comment: @JozefBarca if OP update his question with more hints, I will update my answer. Now it's basic idea - we can set `url` by string, of course.

Comment: as I said It is a great answer

Comment: Thanks guys, will try your solutions